# Teacher and tradition of R' Judah ben Meir HaKohen

Tags: rabbis, ashkenazi, historical-figures, mesorah-tradition

Who was the teacher of [R' Judah ben Meir HaKohen](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9011-judah-ben-meir-ha-kohen-hazaken), and from which chain of tradition does he derive? I ask because I cannot find much information about him online, other than many references to his being the primary teacher of [Rabbeinu Gershom](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6615-gershom-ben-judah). As Rabbeinu Gershom's role in shaping Ashkenazic Jewry cannot be understated, it would [seem to be valuable](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2165/jewish/Chapter-One.htm) to be able to trace his teachers and Mesorah.

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9F

Comment: @DoubleAA, thanks. Unfortunately, that doesn't really address the question, aside from an unsourced sidebar stating that his father, R' Meir HaKohen, was his teacher. It also does not provide any information about R' Meir HaKohen, either.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I did find an obscure website that lists a genealogy for R' Meir HaKohen through the Jewish Khazar kingdom.

Answer (score 5):

Other than his father, the book [Toldoth Yisrael](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36979&hilite=060fabdd-3adc-4404-a3d2-09c2189acf98&st=%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8&pgnum=135) cites the responsa of Solomon Luria (Shu"T RaShaL #29) as claiming that he was a student of Rav Hai Gaon. In the footnotes he discusses the plausibility of such a claim.

Comment: I saw something about this, and it seems dubious. For one thing, his travels from Bavel to Germany are unaccounted for. But thank you for making that connection. I had forgotten that I'd seen it (I can't now remember where I did).

Comment: @SethJ, no problem. I think that it's a stretch too... but possibly the closest you'll get. Do you perchance know anything about רבי מכיר הבבלי?

Comment: Nope...[15char]