# Origins of Ashkenazi Community

Tags: history, nusach-ashkenaz

I saw [a comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47793/mesorah-of-rabbeinu-gershom#comment219008_47793) by mevaqesh:

> To summarize the thesis set forth by R. Dr. Soloveitchik and in
> collected Essays vol. II and elaborated on in vol. III, the Ashkenazic
> mesorah was founded by a group of Babylonian scholars who, annoyed
> with the increasing liberalisation of their "mainstream" Geonic
> counterparts, moved to the Rhineland to start anew. Thus, in spite of
> a few Palestinian/ Italian influences on Ashkenzaic liturgy, their
> massoret in learning is a continuation of those maverick Babylonians.

I would really like to know more about this.

Could someone with access to this sefer provide a quick summary on this? What exactly happened back then, and how did it lead to the current Ashkenazi Jewry we have today?

Comment: You might try reaching out to the Rav at Machon Shilo for more information on this subject. Rabbi Favid Bar Chaim.https://www.machonshilo.org/